# Derivatives of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus

A line segment has one endpoint, A, on the x-axis and the other endpoint, B, on the y-axis. It passes through the point (1,2). If O is the point (0,0), for what value of $<OAB$ is the area of triangle AOB a minimum? What is the minimum area of triangle AOB?

Comment: It looks like something's missing.

Comment: The suspense is killing me...

Comment: Are your question complete?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong !! it's not showing the rest of the Question :/

Comment: @copper.hat yeah u r right

Comment: A line segment has one endpoint, A, on the x-axis and the other endpoint, B, on the y-axis. It passes through the point (1,2). If O is the point (0,0), for what value of <OAB is the area of triangle AOB a minimum? What is the minimum area of triangle AOB?

Comment: @mimzy dont worry it will be fix

Comment: okay here it is, I copied it in here !

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line passing through $A=(a,0)$ and $B=(0,b)$ is $$\dfrac{x}a + \dfrac{y}b = 1$$
We are given that the line passes through the point $(1,2)$. We hence have
$$\dfrac1a + \dfrac2b = 1 \tag{$\star$}$$
The area of the triangle is given by $\Delta=\dfrac{ab}2$.
From AM-GM, we have
$$\dfrac1a + \dfrac2b \geq 2\sqrt{\dfrac1a \cdot \dfrac2b} \tag{$\dagger$}$$
$(\dagger)$ along with $(\star)$ gives us
$$1 \geq \dfrac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{ab}} \implies ab \geq 8 \implies \Delta\geq 4$$
Hence, the minimum area is $4$. Further, the equality occurs if the equality occurs in $\dagger$, which occurs, when $a=2$ and $b=4$. This means $$\tan\left(\angle{OAB}\right) = \dfrac{b}a = 2 \implies \angle{OAB} = \arctan(2)$$

---

**EDIT**

In the figure below the pink triangle represents the triangle with the minimum area, while the blue triangle represents a triangle where the hypotenuse passes through $(1,2)$.

[image]

Comment: why have you assumed $a,b>0?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Else you will get the minimum area as $0$. For instance, consider the line$$\dfrac{x}{-\epsilon} + \dfrac{y}{2\epsilon/(1+\epsilon)} = 1$$ The area of this triangle is $\dfrac{\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon}$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of any line passing through $(1,2)$ is $$\frac{y-2}{x-1}=m$$ where $m$ is the gradient

On re-arrangement , $$\frac x{\frac{m-2}m}+\frac y{-(m-2)}=1$$

So, the area of  $\triangle OAB=\frac12\left| \frac{m-2}m \cdot (2-m)\right|=\frac{(m-2)^2}{2|m|}$

Clearly, $m\ne0$

If $m<0,m=-n$(say) (where n>0) and  we need to minimize  $\frac{(m-2)^2}{-2m}=\frac{(n+2)^2}{2n}$

$$\text{Now,}\frac{(n+2)^2}{2n}=\frac{\left(\sqrt n-\frac2{\sqrt n}\right)^2+4+4}2\ge \frac82=4$$

The minimum value $=4$ occurs if $\sqrt n-\frac2{\sqrt n}=0\implies n=2$

$\implies \tan\angle OAB=-m=+2$ as $m=\tan(\pi-\angle OAB)=-\tan \angle OAB$

$\implies \angle OAB=\arctan(+2)$

If $m>0,\triangle OAB\ge0;$ the equality occurs if $m=2$